# C++11 decltype returns the right type, but code doesnt compile

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I wrote simple analog of std::function for microcontroller because of some important reasons. When I try to test my code, something went wrong and my compiler gave some error about ')' and ',' and so on. The reason was using keyword decltype. I checked the type which decltype returns as Meyers shows. Then I changed the "decltype(...)" to the type decltype deduct and everything went well. I checked my code in compiler explorer on various GCC versions, everything was the same.

Here is the code with decltype (line 102):
 https://godbolt.org/g/4xBkSP
Here the same code with full type written (same line):
https://godbolt.org/g/Er9dFk

Can anybody explain me, please, whats going on?

Comment: Please post the code here, not a link to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, in the `decltype` case the compiler sees the type of your `t` as a *dependent type*. Because of that you have to use

```
t.template bind< typename Deref<decltype( *this )>::Type,
               decltype( &TemplateClassWithCallback::foo3 ),
               &TemplateClassWithCallback::foo3 >( *this );
```

syntax to refer to member template `bind`. Note the extra keyword `template` before `bind`.

When the type of `t` is specified explicitly, it is not seen as a dependent type.

However, according to 14.6.2.2/5, this class member access expression is not supposed to be seen as having dependent type, since it refers to a member of *current instantiation* with a non-dependent type. Yet both GCC and Clang agree on requiring the `template` keyword in this case. (If you compile this with Clang it will actually explicitly tell you to add that `template` keyword.)

Comment: I can't see why it is a dependent type. Can you please provide a Standard quote for backing it up?

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very new way of using keyword template for me)

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: It appears that 14.6.2.2/1 and 2 make it dependent, but per 14.6.2.2/5 it is excluded, if I read 14.6.2.2/5 correctly. Strange.